# wxpython weird bug for TxtCtrl: box is being "clipped"

Tags: python, wxpython

When I run the program on Windows, initially I get this weird bug:

[image]

As you can see the textbox overlaps the border. However, when I click on the box it fixes itself...didn't see this problem when I ran on mac.

Here is my code :

```
    panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

    self.currentDirectory = os.getcwd()

    menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
    fileMenu = wx.Menu()

    self.pathBox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos=(260, 70), size=(240, 20))

    openFileBtn = wx.Button(panel, label="Select Input File", pos=(340, 40))
    openFileBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOpenFile)
    onGo = wx.Button(panel,label="GO!", pos=(340,220))
    setbold = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.ITALIC, wx.BOLD)
    onGo.SetFont(setbold)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onGo)
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to change your code to the minimum amount of code that shows the problem that is runnable including a frame, mainloop ect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the vertical size of the textctrl with -1, so wx will use the default best size for the height of the widget.  If I remember correctly the normal height of single line textctrls on Windows is about 23 pixels, so using 20 will not give it enough room to draw itself the way it wants to.